# Close form in DataRecieved event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, serial-port

i have form that captures a hex code from a serial port. i want to close the form as soon as the hex is captured. but i get an error and cant close the form from `DataReceived` event.

my code :

```
Public hex As String
Dim sp As SerialPort

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim t_hex As String = sp.ReadLine()

        If Len(t_hex) < 21 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        t_hex = Mid(t_hex, 11, 11)

        hex = t_hex
        sp.Close()
        Me.Close() '' ERROR LINE

    End Sub
```

the error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Dlg_CardRead' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

what is the correct way of approaching this and closing the form ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer :

```
Public hex As String
Dim sp As SerialPort

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim t_hex As String = sp.ReadLine()

        If Len(t_hex) < 21 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        t_hex = Mid(t_hex, 11, 11)

        hex = t_hex
        sp.Close()
        CloseMe()

    End Sub

Private Sub CloseMe()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf CloseMe))
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

EDIT :

the problem with the first code was that i was calling methods from Win Forms thread inside another thread. so in another words `DataReceived` event runs in another thread and turns out i can't use `Me.Close()` inside that thread.
The `InvokeRequired` property returns true if you are on any thread other than the UI thread, and the `Invoke` method invokes the given method from the UI thread.

Comment: answers without explanation are not good answers IMHO. Can you elaborate what the problem was and how this fixes it ?

Comment: @GuidoG you are right. edited my answer with further explanation.